# Trouble with proofs regarding a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

As part of an assignment, we must prove that for $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, $\quad U:=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}|AX=XB\}$ ist a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$.
This I have already done with relative ease, as I only need to show three axioms.

The next step is to show that if $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0\\ 
a_3 & a_4
\end{pmatrix}$
and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 & b_2\\ 
0 & b_4
\end{pmatrix}$ then:
$$U = {0} \iff \{a1, a4\} ∩ \{b1, b4\} = ∅.$$

I tried calculating everything with $X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\ 
x_3 & x_4
\end{pmatrix}$ and ended up with a set of equations: 
$a_1x_1=b_1x_1$

$x_3(b_1-a_4)=a_3x_1$

$x_2(a_1-b_4)=b_2x_1$

$x_4(a_4-b_4)=b_2x_3-a_3x_2$

I believe there is a way for me to reformulate these equations so that they fit $\ U=0$ and the intersection, but I keep hitting walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write out that system of equations as a matrix equation.  So,
$$
a_1x_1=b_1x_1\\
x_3(b_1-a_4)=a_3x_1\\
x_2(a_1-b_4)=b_2x_1\\
x_4(a_4-b_4)=b_2x_3-a_3x_2\\
$$
becomes
$$
\pmatrix{a_1 - b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
a_3 & 0 & a_4 - b_1 & 0\\
-b_2 & a_1 - b_4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_3 & -b_2  & a_4 - b_4} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}
$$
Now, when does this system of equations have a unique solution?  Try calculating the determinant of the matrix.

---

You should calculate the determinant to be 
$$
\det(M) = (a_1-b_1)(a_1 - b_4)(a_4 - b_1)(a_4 - b_4)
$$
if any of the terms in the product are $0$, then the determinant of $M$ is zero, which means that $Mx = 0$ has a non-zero solution, which means that there is an element in $U$ besides $X = 0$.  On the other hand, if $\det(M) \neq 0$, then $Mx = 0$ has only the solution $x=0$, which in turn means that $X = 0$ is the only element of $U$.

Comment: By calculating the determinant, I arrived at the conclusion that either $a_1, b_1, a_4, b_4$ are all equal and thus det is 0 or when $\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}$ is the null vector.

Is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I'll add a bit to my answer.

Comment: I expressed myself badly, but your edit is exactly what I meant. Either $x=0$ is the only solution or $det(M)=0$ when any (and therefore all) terms are zero and therefore other elements are present in $U$.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now.  You got it.